# Looking for resources on doing Schnorr signatures in Bitcoin transactions

Tags: transactions, schnorr-signatures

Please leave any resources you think will help, thank you.

Comment: Do you want a wallet that uses P2TR, want to build raw transactions with Schnorr signatures, or implement signing for Schnorr signatures yourself? Could you elaborate the scope of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Wallets that implement p2tr would be helpful for testing, however I am mainly looking for how I would practically implement schnorr transactions in custom code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcoin Optech has held a very good [workshop](https://bitcoinops.org/en/schorr-taproot-workshop/) that you could take a look at.